# White to Black Colour Changing Slider Html?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

So I'm trying to build a slider in html (using jquery) to change the background of the site from white to black (its for a glow in the dark project idea).

I have been looking on the internet and built a working slider for RGB but cant get it just to be white to black and vice versa... Anyone know how to do this? I dont want it to be all the colours of the rainbow just two haha!

My code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Colorpicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #red, #green, #blue {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  #swatch {
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    background-image: none;
  }
  #red .ui-slider-range { background: #ef2929; }
  #red .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #ef2929; }
  #green .ui-slider-range { background: #8ae234; }
  #green .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #8ae234; }
  #blue .ui-slider-range { background: #729fcf; }
  #blue .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #729fcf; }
  </style>
  <script>
  function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
      r.toString( 16 ),
      g.toString( 16 ),
      b.toString( 16 )
    ];
    $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
      if ( val.length === 1 ) {
        hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
      }
    });
    return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
  }
  function refreshSwatch() {
    var red = $( "#red" ).slider( "value" ),
      green = $( "#green" ).slider( "value" ),
      blue = $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" ),
      hex = hexFromRGB( red, green, blue );
    $( "#swatch" ).css( "background-color", "#" + hex );
  }
  $(function() {
    $( "#red, #green, #blue" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      max: 255,
      value: 127,
      slide: refreshSwatch,
      change: refreshSwatch
    });
    $( "#red" ).slider( "value", 255 );
    $( "#green" ).slider( "value", 140 );
    $( "#blue" ).slider( "value", 60 );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body class="ui-widget-content" style="border:0;">

<p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px;">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
  Simple Colorpicker
</p>

<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>

<div id="swatch" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one easy way:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 255,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        val = 255 - ui.value;
        bkgrnd = 'rgb('+val+','+val+','+val+')';
        $('body').css('background-color',bkgrnd)
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/muauc18w/)**

Comment: Thank you Thats brilliant and what i want it to do but when putting into html from jsFiddle it doesn't load? Add to original post

Comment: You need to put the code inside a document ready call (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or at the end of the page.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I thought I had this figured out however I still cant seem to get the document "ready"? Not sure where im going wrong I have followed the webpage you provided... Sorry to be a pain

Comment: Did you wrap the code I posted within a document ready call like the page I linked to shows? Doe you have any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yep $( document ).ready(function() {
 
    // code is here
 
});

Comment: Not from what you've posted. Also please don't post my solution in your question as that may confuse visitors. Have you checked your browser's console for errors?